# Select Values based on Range Automatically and Trigger Email

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers, jobs

The table from which a data range is to be queried :

```
Id  Variance
1     2
2     17
3     7
4     4
5     20
6     1
7     111
8     8
9     18
10    67
```

Another table that has

```
 Freq    StartRange   EndRange
H   10         7
H   8          8
H   6          20
```

The data in the first table is loaded every 30mins through an SSIS package.

Now I want alert as in emails to be triggered when the data in the Variance column falls in the StartRange and EndRange.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Email] @Start varchar(50),@End varchar(50),@Date datetime
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @xml NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @body NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @xml = CAST(( SELECT [SlNo] AS 'td','',[date] AS 'td','',
   [lag] AS 'td','', Percent AS 'td'
FROM  TestTbl 
WHERE(percent >= @Start AND percent < @End)
AND CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR,curDate,106) AS DATETIME) = CAST(@Date AS DATETIME)
ORDER BY SlNo 
FOR XML PATH('tr'), ELEMENTS ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))

SET @body ='<html><body><H3>Report</H3>
<table border = 1> 
<tr>
<th> SlNo </th> <th> date </th> <th> lag </th> <th> Percent </th></tr>'    

SET @body = @body + @xml +'</table></body></html>'

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = 'Alert', 
@body = @body,
@body_format ='HTML',
@recipients = 'abc@gmail.com'
@subject = 'Report';
END
```

Please suggest a process that will help me setup such in SQL Server 2005.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

This can be done via [SQL Server Agent jobs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190268.aspx):

```
EXEC dbo.sp_add_job
    @job_name = N'Variance Check',
    @notify_email_operator_name='you@your.domain',
    @notify_level_email=2; -- Only notify you when YourStoredProceedure fails
GO
EXEC sp_add_jobstep
    @job_name = N'Variance Check',
    @step_name = N'Check the variance',
    @subsystem = N'TSQL',
    @command = N'EXEC YourStoredProceedure', 
    @retry_attempts = 1,
    @retry_interval = 5 ;
GO
EXEC dbo.sp_add_schedule
    @schedule_name = N'EveryThirtyMinutes',
    @freq_type = 4, -- Daily
    @freq_subday_type = 0x4, -- Minutes
    @freq_subday_interval = 30, 
    @active_start_time = NULL; -- Start right away
USE msdb ;
GO
EXEC sp_attach_schedule
   @job_name = N'Variance Check',
   @schedule_name = N'EveryThirtyMinutes';
GO
EXEC dbo.sp_add_jobserver
    @job_name = N'Variance Check';
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to approach this is through triggers.  However, I don't recomment sending emails through triggers.

Instead, add a step to the process that loads the data in T1.  After this step, call a stored procedure that finds the rows that meet the conditions and send the appropriate email.

It is rather hard to tell exactly what the conditions are, however.  Your second table has three ranges.  It is not clear which to apply to which row.

Comment: Only the values under startrange and endrange are to be considered with the Variance column

Comment: @Gallop . . . There are three values in the table, in your example.  Are all three values used?

Comment: Hi Gordon - I have developed a SSIS package that will load data half hourly into the database table.

Only the two values will be used as available in the question

Also a SP has been developed as you suggested it has been updated in the question

But how do I automatically check the database table on hourly basis and if the values fall in range trigger email alert?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: @Gallop . . . I would schedule such a task using a job in SQL Server Agent, and have it run every hour.

Comment: SELECT [SlNo] AS 'td','',[date] AS 'td','',
   [lag] AS 'td','', Percent AS 'td'
FROM  TestTbl 
WHERE(percent >= @Start AND percent < @End)
AND CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR,curDate,106) AS DATETIME) = CAST(@Date AS DATETIME) - I would also want to check any column on condition